# Функция выводит на экран элементы массива в обратном порядке

Tags: c#

Функция должна выводить на экран элементы массива в обратном порядке. Я сделала как  думаю, но не правильно работает. Нужна ваша помощь

```
    static string InverseArray(string[] str)
    {
        string strNew = String.Empty;
        for (int index = str.Length - 1; index >= 0; --index)
        {
            strNew += str[index];
        }
        return strNew;
    }
```

Оно выводит только первый индекс массива и то  не в обратном порядке.

Comment: `static string InverseArray(string[] str)` почему вы принимаете массив строк, а возвращаете одну строку?

Comment: @tym32167 извените. а как правильно  записать? или ретурн в фор  занести?

Comment: Ну а что вы из функции хотите вернуть?

Comment: @tym32167 елементы массива в обратном порядке

Comment: @tym32167   strNew += str[str.Length - i - 1]; от так уже выводит но только слова в обратной форме((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам надо перевернуть массив, это делается вот так:

```
static string[] InverseArray(string[] str)
{
    string[] strNew = new string[str.Length];
    for (int index = 0; index < str.Length; index++)
    {
        strNew[index] += str[str.Length - 1 - index];
    }
    return strNew;
}
```

Использовать можно вот так

```
var array = new[] {"one","two","three"};
foreach(var s in InverseArray(array)) Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Но это по сути то же самое, что и

```
var array = new[] {"one","two","three"};
foreach(var s in array.Reverse()) Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Ну, или, если вам можно прямо исходный массив перевернуть, можно сделать так

```
var array = new[] {"one","two","three"};
Array.Reverse(array);
foreach(var s in array) Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Чтобы перевернуть строку, можно сделать так:

```
static string InverseString(string str)
{
    return new string(str.Reverse().ToArray());
}
```

Если вам надо и массив развернуть, и каждую строку в нем, то можно так

```
var array = new[] {"one","two","three"};    
foreach(var s in array.Reverse()) Console.WriteLine(InverseString(s));
```

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что return возвращает одну строку из массива. Если вы хотите выводи на экран массив в обратном порядке, то это нужно делать в самой функции.
Чтобы вывести массив в обратном порядке, необходимо начинать с конца и идти в начало.

```
static void InverseArray(string[] str)
{
   for (int i = str.Length-1; i >= 0 ; i--)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(str[i]);
   }
}
```

Comment: `Если вы хотите выводи на экран массив в обратном порядке, то это нужно делать в самой функции.` а что если вернуть их функции новый массив и его уже выводить как и где хочется?

Comment: @XMarin  вы  не свосем мой вопрос  поняли. мне  нужно - "Hello world" - "dlrow olleH" а  зараз у Вас и уже у меня -strNew += str[str.Length - i - 1];  так пишеться - "world Hello"

Comment: @tym32167 а я  просто создала  стринговое  значение и как 1  строку вывожу весь масив,  это плохо?

Comment: @OksanaVol это зависит от вашей задачи. Вы сначала пишете о массиве строк, а теперь вам надо строку перевернуть. Вы определитесь, что вы хотите

Comment: @tym32167, тогда `return Array.Reverse(str);`

Comment: @XMarin ну да, либо метод расширения использовать, `str.Reverse();`, но, судя по комментам автора, это уже не то, что ему надо :)

Comment: @tym32167 нет то что надо)

Comment: @tym32167 я изменила код. Посмотрите  нормальный  ли он,  я  только  изучаю и много еще не  шару,  поэтому  буду  рада  критике и помощи)

Answer (score 0):

```
    static string Reverse(string s) 
    {
      string temp = "";
      int i, j;
      //Console.WriteLine("Обращение строки.");
      for(j=0, i=s.Length-1; i >= 0; i--, j++)
      temp += s[i];
    }
```

Метод вернет строку наоборот